# 'Error: expected expression' keeps returning. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c

So I am very new to C programming and I am stuck.

I am writing some code that reads certain data from a file (defined by my read_file function). One of my tasks was to also covert the distance between 2 given points (as seen by void distance) and convert that to radians (as seen by toRadian).

The issue however lies on line 48 (highlighted in the code), where I am getting

> "error: expected expression
>   chord_length = pow(sin(toRadian(lat_2 - LAT_1)/2) + cos(toRadian
>
> program.c:6:15: note: expanded from macro 'LAT_1'
>
> define LAT_1 −37.798185"

What Have I done wrong? I just can't work it out.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LAT_1 -78.98214
#define LONG_1 -7.31600
#define R_PI 3.14159
#define DEGREES 180

int read_file(int i);
void toRadian(double theta);
void distance(double d);

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    return read_file(i);
}

void toRadian(double theta)
{
    double x = 0;
    x = R_PI/DEGREES;
}

void distance(double d)
{
/* This function is designed to calculate the distance between the check-in 
POI and the reference point provided*/
double dist, angle_distance, chord_length;
char *lat_2, *long_2;

    char length[256];
    char *token[6];

    if (fgets(length, 256, stdin) != NULL) 
    {
        token[0] = strtok(length, " ");
        int i = 0;
        double dist;
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            lat_2 = token[1];
            long_2 = token[2];
        }

    chord_length = pow(sin(toRadian(lat_2 - LAT_1)/2) + cos(toRadian
    (LAT_1)) * cos(toRadian(lat_2)) * pow(sin(toRadian(long_2 - 
    LONG_1))));

    angle_distance = 2 * atan2(sqrt(chrod_length), sqrt(1 - cord_length));

    dist = 6371 * angle_dist;
}

int read_file(int i) 
{
    /* This function takes the data from the input file,reading and printing the 
    User ID, Location (longitude and latitude), Date, Time, and Distance*/
    char length[256];
    char *token[6];

    if (fgets(length, 256, stdin) != NULL) 
    {
        token[0] = strtok(length, " ");
        int i = 0;
        double dist;
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            token[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); /*C programming is fun*/
            printf("Stage 1\n==========\n");
            printf("User: #%s\n", token[0]); 
            printf("Location: <%s, %s>\n", token[1], token[2]);
            printf("Date: %s\n", token[3]);
            printf("Time: %s\n", token[4]);
            printf("Distance to reference: %2.2f\n", distance(dist));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file. Check file and try again.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many, many compile errors. Start by correcting the `toRadian` function which is total nonsense. Then consider if it makes sense to substract a `double` from a char pointer (as seen in `toRadian(lat_2 - LAT_1)`).

Comment: You should probably start learning C by writing some simpler programs.

Comment: Your `toRadian` and `distance` functions have a return type of `void`. You probably need to change the return type to `double` and `return` a value.

Comment: Probably also `lat_2 = token[1]` -> `lat_2 = atof(token[1])`. You're mixing up variables of type `double` with variables of type `pointer to char` (`char*`).

Comment: Also (but the least of your problems right now) `3.14159` is a pretty poor aproximation of PI.

Comment: The `if` statement block in function `distance` is missing a `}` on the end.

Comment: I have no idea why the `for` loop in function `distance` needs to do the same thing 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting a float from a pointer (lat_2 - LAT_1). This doesn't make any sense.

Also your passing it to toRadian() that takes a double and return nothing... it's all wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat corrected version of your program. It compiles almost with no errors.

Read carefully the comments starting with `***`.

Probably there are more errors, but it's a start.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LAT_1 -78.98214
#define LONG_1 -7.31600

#define R_PI 3.14159       // *** correct and put PI with more decimals
#define DEGREES 180

int read_file(int i);
double toRadian(double theta);   // *** correct declaration
double distance(double d);    // *** correct declaration

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  return read_file(i);
}

double toRadian(double theta)
{
  double x;   // *** no need to initialize with 0
  x = R_PI / DEGREES;  // *** something is missing here: up to to find what
                       //     Hint: you need to use the theta parameter
  return x;
}

double distance(double d)   // ** correct prototype
{
  /* This function is designed to calculate the distance between the check-in
  POI and the reference point provided*/
  double dist, angle_distance, chord_length;
  double lat_2, long_2;  // *** double here

  char length[256];
  char* token[6];

  if (fgets(length, 256, stdin) != NULL)
  {
    token[0] = strtok(length, " ");
    int i = 0;
    double dist;
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)     // *** what's the purpose of this for loop???
    {
      lat_2 = atof(token[1]);   // *** using atof here
      long_2 = atof(token[2]);
    }

    chord_length = pow(sin(toRadian(lat_2 - LAT_1) / 2) + cos(toRadian
    (LAT_1)) * cos(toRadian(lat_2)) * pow(sin(toRadian(long_2 -
      LONG_1))));   // *** no idea what the formula should be , but pow needs 2 arguments

    angle_distance = 2 * atan2(sqrt(chord_length), sqrt(1 - chord_length)); // *** using chord_length

    dist = 6371 * angle_distance;   // *** using angle_distance
    return dist;    // *** the function must return something.
  }
}    // *** this } was missing

int read_file(int i)  // *** what's the purpose if the i parameter?
{
  /* This function takes the data from the input file,reading and printing the
  User ID, Location (longitude and latitude), Date, Time, and Distance*/
  char length[256];
  char* token[6];

  if (fgets(length, 256, stdin) != NULL)
  {
    token[0] = strtok(length, " ");
    int i = 0;
    double dist;
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
      token[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); /*C programming is fun*/

    printf("Stage 1\n==========\n");
    printf("User: #%s\n", token[0]);
    printf("Location: <%s, %s>\n", token[1], token[2]);
    printf("Date: %s\n", token[3]);
    printf("Time: %s\n", token[4]);
    printf("Distance to reference: %2.2f\n", distance(dist));
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Error opening file. Check file and try again.");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HassSugma the formula that converts from deg to rad must include the angle you want to convert